# Trying to run a scala script, conscript errors when install "sbt/sbt"

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to install sbt/sbt with conscript on OSX

`cs sbt/sbt --branch 0.13.8`

following the sbt doc: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scripts.html

I got the following errors:

```
.......

[SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.6!apply-macro.jar (4702ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    44 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (13750kB/113ms)
[error] Not a valid command: version (similar: session)
[error] version
[error]        ^
[error] Not a valid command: version
[error] version
[error]        ^
[error] Not a valid command: version
[error] version
[error]        ^

Conscripted sbt/sbt to ~bin/sbt
Conscripted sbt/sbt to ~/bin/scalas
Conscripted sbt/sbt to ~/bin/screpl
```

`scalas` and `screpl` seem installed correctly? But, when I tried to execute the following script `helloworld.scala`,

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalas

/***
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
*/

println("hello")
```

I got errors like:

```
>./helloworld.scala
~ ./helloworld.scala:5: error: eof expected but ';' found.
  */
^
[error] Error parsing expression.  Ensure that settings are separated by blank lines.
```

Another script example `test.scala`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalas

/***
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.2"
  */
import dispatch._, Defaults._
case class Location(city: String, state: String)
    def weatherSvc(loc: Location) = {
      host("api.wunderground.com") / "api" / "5a7c66db0ba0323a" /
        "conditions" / "q" / loc.state / (loc.city + ".xml")
    }
    val nyc = Location("New York", "NY")
    for (str <- Http(weatherSvc(nyc) OK as.String))
      println(str)
```

I got errors like:

```
./test.scala:18: error: not found: value Location
val nyc = Location("New York", "NY")
          ^
./test.scala:14: error: not found: value host
  host("api.wunderground.com") / "api" / "5a7c66db0ba0323a" /
  ^
./test.scala:13: error: not found: type Location
def weatherSvc(loc: Location) = {
                    ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.checkError(Eval.scala:384)
......
```

Could anybody suggest?

Comment: The error seems to be a bug of the " --version" flag https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1857#issuecomment-74183037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the whitespace(`"  */"`) in the head of last comment line failed. IntelliJ automatically add space to prettify the comments (or is it scala convention to add whitespace?) but `scalas` doesn't strip it.